# How can I concat two strings with tab in bash?

Tags: bash, echo, concatenation

There's a snippet code here.

```
$ a=aa
$ b=bb
$ echo -e $a"\t"$b
aa       bb
$ c=`echo -e $a"\t"$b`
$ echo $c
aa bb
$ echo -e $c
aa bb
```

I wanna concat the $a and $b with tab, and set the result to variable c for a further use.

But When I echo $c, no tab display, only a space.

What should I do?

Comment: In `bash`, a simpler way to embed the tab is `c="$a"$'\t'"$b"`. Hmm. Maybe not simpler, but it does avoid a fork, since `$'\t'` is interpreted directly by the shell, instead of needing a subprocess to capture the output of `echo`. In `bash` 4 or greater, you can also use `printf -v c "%s\t%s" "$a" "$b"` to print directly to a variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo "$c"
```

You need to quote the variable.  Moreover, since you already *interpreted* the escape sequence during the assignment to `c`, you don't need to specify `-e` while echoing the value.